# Using the eval command twice

Tags: shell-script, shell, quoting, escape-characters, eval

Suppose:

```
a=b; b=c; c=d
```

Then `eval echo \$$a` produces the output:

```
c
```

If we want to extract the output `d` using just input `a`, I tried the following way:

(i) `eval echo \$(eval echo \$$a)` produces the error:

```
syntax error near unexpected token '('
```

(ii) `eval echo \$\(eval echo \$$a\)` produces the output:

```
c
```

I am not able to understand why escape slashing the bracket got rid of the error.

Also, could someone please explain why I didn't get the output as `d` in the second instance?

Comment: See [Eval command and security issues](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048)

Comment: @Wildcard I am new to bash shell programming. The link which you provided is a bit tough to me. Could you please explain in simple words where I went wrong?

Comment: Sure.  From a security standpoint, it's a really bad idea to use `eval` in *any* shell script unless you know *exactly* what you're doing.  (And even then, there are virtually zero instances where it is actually the best solution.)  As a beginner to shell scripting, please just forget that `eval` even exists.  :)

Comment: @Wildcard ohk.. I understand but I would be really grateful if you could pin point where I went wrong in my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, a word of caution:

From a security standpoint, it's a really bad idea to use `eval` in *any* shell script unless you know *exactly* what you're doing. (And even then, there are virtually zero instances where it is actually the best solution.) As a beginner to shell scripting, please just forget that `eval` even exists.

For further reading, see [Eval command and security issues](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048).

---

To get the output `d`, you could use:

```
eval echo \$${!a}
```

Or:

```
eval eval echo \\\$\$$a
```

---

Where you went wrong was in passing the unescaped parentheses characters to `echo`.  If they are preceded by an unquoted `$`, it is command substitution.  But if the `$` is quoted and *not* the parentheses, it isn't valid shell syntax.

Answer (score 3):

Nested evals are a messy thing.

First,

```
eval echo \$\(eval echo \$$a\)
```

causes the interpreter to evaluate the following:

```
echo $(eval echo $b)
```

Interpolating the innermost nested command (i.e. `$(eval echo $b)`) results in:

```
echo c
```

Which gives you the result:

```
c
```

If you want the nested evals to get evaluated correctly (and I highly recommend **not** using `eval` to **at all**), you have to get pretty weird.  See other answers for examples.

Comment: Thanks. Could you also please explain why back slashing the parenthesis was important here

Answer (score 1):

You could get the expected output `d` with the
 following :

```
eval echo \$$(echo ${!a})
```

`${!a}` is a bash variable name expansion that gives `c` with your values. See [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).